# Strip SSML or is there other way?

Tags: actions-on-google

My webhook is currently using SSML as a response to Actions On Google. It workes great when using Google Assistant.

Not so much with Telegram and the new Web Simulator (not the one with analytics, the new one). Both messengers outputs SSML instead of the displayText.

Is there a way to let the other messengers use displayText instead of the SSML? Or should I change my code and add messages specifically forspeech and display text?

If that's the case, should I use an XML parser to strip out the SSML from the original message and add the result as the display text?

Comment: Can you check the source of the request and provide one of two different responses? Trying to strip XML seems like a difficult task with many edge cases.

Comment: I could but it would mean it's going to take a bit of code. Hahaha! It would be easier to create a new message for displayText without XML stripping :D